# $x^{2n} + x^{2n-1} + x^ {2n-2} +\ldots+ x + 1$ is irreducible for any $n\in \mathbb N$ in $F_2[x]$. True or false?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Will the  polynomials of the following set $A$  be irreducible in $F_2[x]$?

$A = [x^{2n} + x^{2n-1} + x^ {2n-2} + \ldots+ x + 1 : n\in \mathbb N]$

Can anyone please give me hints how to proceed?

Every term is there. I meant every polynomial of degree $2n$ has $2n+1$ terms.

Comment: Are you intending to omit any terms among the $x^i$ and if yes then which?

Comment: No no every term is there. I mean every polynomial of degree $2n$ has $2n+1$ terms.@SorinTirc

Comment: I am asking this because you omitted $x^{2n-2}$ so maybe you should correct that and then my answer below should be an answer to your question

Answer (score 2):

It's false in general, for example for $n=4$ : $x^8+x^7+x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1 = (x^2+x+1)(x^6+x^3+1)$.

In general $\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}$ is irreducible iff n is prime(the cyclotomic poly) over $ \mathbb{Q}[X]$

Comment: I think it's intended to omit the terms $x^6, x^4, x^2$.

Comment: oh, didn't see that, but then I am not quite sure exactly which terms are omitted tbh

Comment: All the even terms are omitted except the first one.

Comment: and the last one $x^0$ then too maybe :) ? In whice case the n=2 poly is reducible :)

Comment: Can we say if a polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$ so will be in $F_2[x]$?@SorinTirc

Comment: Can we say if a polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$ so will be in $F_2[x]$?@Slade

Comment: "In general $\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}$ is irreducible iff n is prime(the cyclotomic poly) over $ \mathbb{Q}[X]$"  what is the significance of this line in my question? @SorinTirc

Comment: Well what you can say is that in order for a poly to be irreducible over $F_2$, it has to be irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ in the first place. It’s an “if” relationship not an “if and only if relationship” and I thought I would just mention it. In your problem I proved that your poly is reducible over Q hence a fortiori over $F_2$